# When MP4 files encoded with H264 are set to slices=n, where can I find out how many slices the current NALU is?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, encoding, mp4, h.264

I am doing an experiment on generating thumbnails for web videos. I plan to extract I-frames from the binary stream by simulating the working principle of the decoder, and add the PPS and SPS information of the original video to form the H264 raw information, which is then handed over to ffmpeg to generate images. I have almost solved many problems, and even wrote a demo to implement my function, but I can't find any information about where there is an identifier when multiple NALUs form one frame (strictly speaking, there is a little, but it can't solve my problem, I will talk about it later).

You can use the following command to generate the type of video I mentioned:

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -x264-params slices=8 output.mp4
```

This will generate a video with 8 slices per frame. Since I will use this file later, I will also generate the H264 raw information file with the following command:

```
 ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vcodec copy -an output.h264
```

When I put it into the analysis program, I can see multiple IDR NALUs connected together, where the first_mb_in_slice in the Slice Header of the non-first IDR NALU is not 0:
[image]

But when I go back to the mdat in MP4 and look at the NALU, all the first_mb_in_slice become 0:
[image]

0x9a= 1001 1010, according to the exponential Golomb coding, first_mb_in_slice == 0( ueg(1B) == 0 ), slice_type == P frame (ueg(00110B) == 5), but using the same algorithm in the H264 raw file, the result is the same as the program gives.

Is there any other place where there is an identifier for this information? Assuming I randomly get a NALU, can I know if this video is sliced or not, or is my operation wrong?

PS: Putting only one NALU into the decoder is feasible, but only 1/8 of the image can be parsed
[image]

If you need a reference, the address of the demo program I wrote is: https://github.com/gaowanliang/web-video-thumbnailer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *" I plan to extract I-frames"*

Make sure you go for **IDR** keyframes (not **I-frame** keyframes) since IDR bytes can decode into a complete image. Some I-frames can actually need other P/B frames to make a complete image.

> *"I can't find any information about where there is an identifier when multiple NALUs form one frame"*

##### Handling at MP4 level:

**(1) Using SEI:** (NALU type **6**, usually as byte `0x06`)

***solution:*** Find text `slices=` in the SEI text.

The MP4 might contain SEI bytes, which will be in front of the bytes of the first video frame. 
SEI is text data, and if using **libx264** as encoder then, it includes a `"slices="` entry.

*An example of SEI text in a libx264 encode:*

```
cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex ... (other texts)
sliced_threads=0 slices=8 nr=0 decimate=1 ... (other texts)
constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 ... (other texts)
```

Usually IDR is one big slice (*ie:* Really libx264? We slice IDR frames now? For what benefit though?).

Using `-x264-params slices=8` will overwrite the 1-slice default. As you can see there is now a `"slices=8"` text entry which tells us to find: **8 NAL units per frame** (including even if IDR).

**(2) Using STSS and STSZ:**

***solution:***  A size (or bytes-length) listed in STSZ will include all NALU slices per frame.

- "stss" == bytes (hex) `73 74 73 73` == integer `0x73747373`.
- "stsz" == bytes (hex) `73 74 73 7A` == integer `0x7374737A`.

The MP4's **video track** will have a Sample Table. It has an STSS section for listing all IDR keyframes. Then it has an STSZ section for listing the bytes-length of all frames.

Using these two sections of the MP4 header, you can find out which frame numbers that are representing IDR, then check the size by matching the STSZ entry's number to the related frame number.

Extract a keyframe by the shown size in STSZ to get a full frame (with all NALU slices).

##### Handling at H.264  level:

**(1) Using SEI:** (NALU type **6**, usually as byte `0x06`)

*solution:* Find text `slices=` in the SEI text.

The same process as with MP4 (as explained above).

**(2) Using first_mb_in_slice:**

*solution:* The value of `first_mb_in_slice` is **1** for first slice and **0** for all other slices of the frame.

You get **first_mb_in_slice** by checking the first bit of the next byte after NALU header **0x65**.

In the case of 8 slices (per frame), when you find an IDR frame, the **first_mb_in_slice** will be a **1** for the first slice, then following is another 7 IDR units each with a `first_mb_in_slice` of **0**.

You will know that you have enough NALUs for one frame when:

- The `first_mb_in_slice` of the next IDR becomes **1** again (it means this is now a different IDR).
- Or when you get the NALU header type of a P/B frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I wanted to say at the beginning was that there would be a Slices=8 identifier in the SEI header, but I forgot it as I was writing . The reason why I said this could not solve my problem was that even after knowing slices=8, I could not tell which slice it was when I randomly got a nalu. Today I compared the mp4 and the .h264 raw stream file parsed by ffmpeg in detail, and found that slices=n would cause a sample to contain n nalus. I always thought that there was only one nalu in a sample, so I always thought that stsz was the length of the nalu.

Answer (score 2):

H.264 comes in two formats. Let's call them mp4 and Annex B.

In Annex B your video frames are Access Units (AUs).

On disk or on the wire it looks like this:

```
|Access Unit Delimiter| |PPS| |SPS| |Slice (1)| |Slice (2)| ... |Slice (n)| |Access Unit Delimiter|
```

You have to parse the slice header to determine I, P or B frame.
You have to count the slices until you hit the next Access Unit Delimiter or end of stream.

In Annex B the various NAL units (Access Unit Delimiter, PPS and Slices) are separated by delimiters '0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01'

In MP4 the NAL units are prefixes with their size.
So read the size, read the type of NAL unit (for example slice), parse the slice header to determine I,P or B, go to the next NAL unit.
In MP4 the container will tell you how big the Access Unit is - so you don't have to look for Access Unit Delimiters.

In both case (Annex B or MP4) you can simply count the number of slices in one access unit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however, in mp4, the vast majority of encodings that are currently mainstream are avcC, not Annex B.